# Multilingual slug with django-translated-fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-translated-fields

I am trying to implement a multilingual Django website with help of [django-translated-fields](https://github.com/matthiask/django-translated-fields).

The project I am working on is based on [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) and Docker.

The translation works fine for my model fields – except the slug filed. Actually translation of slug works as well but I am not able to take slug field for getting one single entry.

**Excerpt of voting model:**

```
class Voting(models.Model):
    slug =  TranslatedField(
        models.SlugField(
            max_length=80,
            unique=True,
            verbose_name="Voting URL slug",
            blank=True
        ),
        {
            "de": {"blank": True},
            "fr": {"blank": True},
            "it": {"blank": True},
            "rm": {"blank": True},
            "en": {"blank": True},
        },
    )
```

Full voting model of project can be seen [here](https://github.com/Apfelschuss/apfelschuss/blob/427a670a0877e050bf9ca8cd5e4d8fff15ff856f/apfelschuss/votes/models.py#L82-L96).

**Excerpt of view:**

```
def voting(request, slug):
    voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'voting': voting
    }
    return render(request, 'votes/single.html', context)
```

Full view can be seen [here](https://github.com/Apfelschuss/apfelschuss/blob/427a670a0877e050bf9ca8cd5e4d8fff15ff856f/apfelschuss/votes/views.py#L84-L91)

Since Django translated fields creates `slug_en`, `slug_de` and so on I cannot find a solution for getting the slug in corresponding language.

It should be obvious since documentation of Django-translated fields says:

*No model field is actually created. The TranslatedField instance is a descriptor which by default acts as a property for the current language's field.*

Unfortunately, don’t get it anyway. Any idea how I can change voting model for getting the entry in the specific language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from translated_fields import to_attribute

def voting(request, slug):
    voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, **{to_attribute(name='slug'): slug})
    context = {
        'voting': voting
    }
    return render(request, 'votes/single.html', context)
```

If necessary, you can add `language_code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE` to the call to `to_attribute`, but usually this is not necessary:

```
    voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, **{to_attribute(name='slug', language_code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE): slug})
```

Comment: Thank you Uri for this solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way but with help of Django Documentation “[How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)” I came to following solution.

**Changing the voting view as follows:**

```
def voting(request, slug):
    '''Takes slug of single voting and returns that voting object in
    corresponding language.
    '''
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de':
        voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug_de=slug)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr':
        voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug_fr=slug)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'it':
        voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug_it=slug)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'rm':
        voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug_rm=slug)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en':
        voting = get_object_or_404(Voting, slug_en=slug)
    context = {
        'voting': voting
    }
    return render(request, 'votes/single.html', context)
```

Comment: You can use `to_attribute` with `*` to use the `LANGUAGE_CODE` in one line. In this case you don't have to define it 5 times like you did.

Comment: Something like `get_object_or_404(Voting, **{to_attribute(name='slug'): slug})`

Comment: If necessary, you can add `language_code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE` to the call to `to_attribute`.